# R - Convert integer to hour / minutes

Tags: r, datetime

Thank you for entering this thread, I belive this is a simple question so here it goes.

I have two columns, one for HOURS and one for MINUTES on a 24:60 format, both columns are INTEGERS AND I want to create a column on TIME(?) format, example:

```
Hour(Integer)        Minutes(Integer)        Time Column
      5                     30                  5:30
      7                     27                  7:27
     11                     05                 11:05
     17                     45                 17:45
     22                     15                 22:15
```

That´s pretty much it, thank you.

Edit: Shree answers only gives Characters

Comment: How about `paste0(your_df$Hour, ":", your_df$Minutes)`?

Comment: @shree but that wouldn't be a POSIXct and POSIXlt wouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df <- tribble(
~Hour,~Minutes,
5,30,
7,27,
11,05,
17,45,
22,15)

df %>% 
  mutate(time = str_c(Hour,Minutes,sep = ":")) %>% 
  mutate(time = time %>% hm())
```

Comment: Bruno, I'm picking yours since it's the simplest solution. Ty.

Comment: Is `time %>% hm()` better looking or more readable than `hm(time)`?

Answer (score 5):

Base R, using @Bruno's data:

```r
paste(df$Hour, df$Minutes, sep=":")
# [1] "5:30"  "7:27"  "11:5"  "17:45" "22:15"

as.POSIXct(paste(df$Hour, df$Minutes, sep=":"), format = "%H:%M", tz = "GMT")
# [1] "2019-06-05 05:30:00 GMT" "2019-06-05 07:27:00 GMT"
# [3] "2019-06-05 11:05:00 GMT" "2019-06-05 17:45:00 GMT"
# [5] "2019-06-05 22:15:00 GMT"
```

I specifically included `tz=` in the call, mostly for "good practice" since base R `POSIXt` functions apply none by default (which means it *infers*, but does not state, your current tz). It works fine without this.

Note that this will always default to "today" (when you run `as.POSIXct`), since we are not specifying a day/date in our call.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, if I were to follow your suggestion, I understand that there's no way to hide the YY/MM/DD info? As I just need HH:MM

Comment: You cannot have `POSIXt` in R without it. When you want to display it, you can always use `format` to include just the part you want, but then it will be `character`, and not time/math-friendly. There are libraries/packages that masks this from you, I'm confident.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do this, as you can tell by the amount of responses. But a path I always find easier is to use `lubridate::parse_date_time` because it is possible to work around this and many other data manipulation issues for this class.

```
df <- data.frame(Hour = c(5,7,11,17,22), 
             Minutes  = c(30,27,05,45,15))

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Time = format(strptime(lubridate::parse_date_time(paste(Hour, Minutes, sep = ":"), 'H:M'),
                                       "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),'%H:%M'))

# Or in a more didactic way
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Time = paste(Hour, Minutes, sep = ":"),
                Time = lubridate::parse_date_time(Time, 'H:M'),
                Time = format(strptime(Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),'%H:%M'))
```

Comment: Your's it's the most elaborate answer and so I have a question (I haven't run your code, I'm writing from my Smartphone) but, Why do I need the last line?  ...Format (strptime)...

Comment: For only hour and minute to remain, it is a disadvantage of using `lubridate::parse_date_time`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution.  This just creates a character variable.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(Hour = c(5,7,11,17,22), Minutes  = c(30,27,05,45,15))

df %>% 
  mutate(Time = str_c(Hour, Minutes, sep = ':'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the will come handy one day.